# Return Vales when

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting, maxdate

I'm stuck here, guys.

I have two tables, each having a date column.  One table is using timestamp (2016-08-05 09:16:11.000) the other has timestamp but isn't using it (2016-08-05 00:00:00.000)

I want to join these tables and return the MAX date from each table but ONLY when the MAX dates match. If one column has a more recent date, display the results when both columns had a matching max date.

I'm trying MAX and CAST(to remove timestamp)but I can only pull back the MAX date from each table. So it's not showing me the same dates when both tables don't have the same max date.

Here's my example

```
SELECT A.ID,
CAST(A.DATE as date),
CAST(B.DATE as date),
B.NUMBER,
A.VALUE,

FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE 2 B
ON A.ID = B.ID

Where b.DATE=(SELECT MAX(DATE)
FROM TABLE B
WHERE ID = b.ID) 

Where A.DATE=(SELECT MAX(DATE)
FROM TABLE A
WHERE ID = b.ID)
```

I want my results to be something like this:

```
ID | (no column name)| (no column name) | Number| Value |
1  | 2016-08-04      | 2016-08-04       | 42    | 77    | 
2  | 2016-08-04      | 2016-08-04       | 43    | 40    | 
3  | 2016-08-04      | 2016-08-04       | 44    | 42    |
```

But when they don't have the same max date, I get this

```
ID | (no column name)| (no column name) | Number| Value |
1  | 2016-08-04      | 2016-08-05       | 42    | 47    | 
2  | 2016-08-04      | 2016-08-05       | 43    | 43    | 
3  | 2016-08-04      | 2016-08-05       | 44    | 44    |
```

Hopefully I made myself clear. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. When the max dates are not equal what do you want to show?

Comment: Always show the max date when they're the same. If not the same, show the previous time each column matched dates.

Comment: So you want to to JOIN the tables on MAX(date)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `row_number`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT A.ID,
           CAST(A.DATE as date),
           CAST(B.DATE as date),
           B.NUMBER,
           A.VALUE,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY A.Date DESC) rn
    FROM TABLE1 A 
           JOIN TABLE 2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
                        AND CAST(A.DATE as date) = CAST(B.DATE as date)
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: That's what I needed!  Thanks a bunch